# Create convenience functions (batch commands) in Ruby console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

During development I found myself checking the some results in the Ruby console everyday. This is done by typing the same commands with different parameters every time. However these command can be long, or sometimes several commands need to run sequentially.

For example:

`Nokogiri.HTML(open(Rails.root.join('page/p1.html')))`

I am wondering if it is possible to specify some convenience functions, which automatically gets loaded when I run the console? So I can call complex calls anytime I want in the console.

I also heard that there are console replacements. So it doesn't have to be the native console, as long as it offers similar functionalities.

Comment: If you press the UP arrow on the keyboard it should iterate through your history.  IRB doesn't seem to do this by default, but Pry does.

Comment: Also, IRB and Pry both have optional init scripts at `~/.irbrc` and `~/.pryrc`, which quite simply contain ruby code executed when they are opened.

Comment: You could also write a small ruby script and just execute that?

Comment: Thanks it worked (I am using Rib now and it has `.rib/config.rb`, which is probably the same thing. Do you want to write an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As d11wtq pointed out, according to the console you use, you can use the its configuration file to write your own convenience functions:

IRB has ~/.irbrc

PRY has ~/.pryrc

RIB has ~/.rib/config.rb

Place the code in these and you can call them in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about automatically, but you can create a ruby module, put all your useful stuff in there as methods, and just require/include that at the start of using the console.